# how to change TextBox Focus in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working in Windows Form framework of c# , i have developed a form consisting of two textboxes (name and address). Problem is when i start my application focus is on address rather then name, how can i change this settings? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Get the Load-Event and in this event call tbName.Focus() or you can change the tab-order in the form.

Comment: i have tried tab order, name box has 1 and address is 2 ... Still not working.

Comment: Do you want the focus or the access for user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Form_Load` event call:

```
yourTextBox.Focus();
```

You may look at [Control.Focus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on msdn

You may also look at this article to [Set the Tab order](http://www.platinumbay.com/blogs/dotneticated/archive/2007/12/10/winforms-tab-order.aspx) if you don't want to use `Focus()`

Comment: All Are best answers, but this one is the best in all. :) Thank You Very Much.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this ll help you. Select will change for user input

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBoxName.Select();
        textBoxName.Focus();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the Tab Index property of the textbox as 0. Otherwise you can set call the focus method on load event

Answer (score 1):

set focus on the text box like this

```
txtbxname.Focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the ActiveControl property. Never failed me as of today.

```
ActiveControl = Address;
```